# Объясните работу кода php что код делает

Tags: php

```
Объясните работу кода


<?php ## Различие текстового и бинарного режимов.
  // Получает в параметрах строку и возвращает через пробел коды 
  // символов, из которых она состоит.
  function makeHex($st)
  {  
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($st); $i++)
      $hex[] = sprintf("%02X", ord($st[$i]));
    return join(" ", $hex);
  }
  // Открываем файл скрипта разными способами
  $f = fopen(__FILE__, "rb");  // бинарный режим
  echo makeHex(fgets($f, 100)), "<br />\n";
  $f = fopen(__FILE__, "rt"); // текстовый режим
  echo makeHex(fgets($f, 100)), "<br />\n";
?>


3C 3F 70 68 70 20 23 23 20 D0 A0 D0 B0 D0 B7 D0 BB D0 B8 D1 87 D0 B8 D0 B5 20 D1 82 D0 B5 D0 BA D1 81 D1 82 D0 BE D0 B2 D0 BE D0 B3 D0 BE 20 D0 B8 20 D0 B1 D0 B8 D0 BD D0 B0 D1 80 D0 BD D0 BE D0 B3 D0 BE 20 D1 80 D0 B5 D0 B6 D0 B8 D0 BC D0 BE D0 B2 2E 0D 0A
3C 3F 70 68 70 20 23 23 20 D0 A0 D0 B0 D0 B7 D0 BB D0 B8 D1 87 D0 B8 D0 B5 20 D1 82 D0 B5 D0 BA D1 81 D1 82 D0 BE D0 B2 D0 BE D0 B3 D0 BE 20 D0 B8 20 D0 B1 D0 B8 D0 BD D0 B0 D1 80 D0 BD D0 BE D0 B3 D0 BE 20 D1 80 D0 B5 D0 B6 D0 B8 D0 BC D0 BE D0 B2 2E 0D 0A
```

Comment: `## Различие текстового и бинарного режимов.` - комментарий, точно такой же, как и `// Получает в параметрах строку...`. Вам это объяснить надо, или же сам код что делает?

Comment: сам код что делает

Comment: Бегает циклом и добавляет каждый символ строки в массив, в определенном формате, потом склеивает массив обратно в строку. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php

Comment: `$f = fopen(__FILE__, "rb");` открывается файл, `echo makeHex(fgets($f, 100)), "<br />\n";` - в функцию makeHex передаётся строка длиной 100 байт с открытого файла, и, соответственно, результат выводится. Сама функция в аргументы принимает строку, которая разбивается по-байтно, преобразовывается в число (ord()), форматируется спецификатором преобразования (%02X, подробнее [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)) и записывается в массив  $hex[], который в последующем преобразовывается в строку

Comment: $hex[] = sprintf("%02X", ord($st[$i]));